# Request Tracker API V2 Add Multiple Requestors

Tags: rest, rt

I'm trying to add multiple requestors to an RT ticket. I can set a single requestor successfully, but when I go to add another, it just overwrites the current requestor.

Currently, the body text I'm sending in the PUT request is:

```
{"Requestor": "email"}
```

I've tried comma seperating the email addresses for the value field as well as trying to pass them as a JSON array.

I may just be missing it in the documentation here (https://github.com/bestpractical/rt-extension-rest2), but does anyone have any guidance for me on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a JSON array of email addresses as the Requestor field.
`{"Requestor": ["email1@domain.com", "email2@domain.com"]}`

Comment: This worked. I must not have been formatting the JSON array properly in the request. Thank you!